# Circular Intermediate with background color in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to make circular intermediate progress bar in jetpack compose. I tried some piece of code but it's not working correctly to animate the circle. I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72151319/8266651) as well, but nothing works

```
           val strokeWidth = dimensionResource(R.dimen.stroke)
           Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                progress = .25f,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
                    .drawBehind {
                        drawCircle(
                            Cloudy,
                            radius = size.width / 2 - strokeWidth.toPx() / 2,
                            style = Stroke(strokeWidth.toPx())
                        )
                    },
                color = Aqua,
                strokeWidth = strokeWidth
             )
          }
```

**Actual Output**

The animation is not working

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why the expected output should be this. Your progress = 0.5 -> half circle.

Comment: Oh sorry I have to change to less around to .25f something

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I updated the code. The problem is the animation is not working.

Comment: the animation doesn't work because the progress has a fixed value

Comment: So is there way we can fix the problem?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I tried to remove `progress = .25f` then animation works but I want my expected output

Comment: Do you want to have an indeterminate progress animating the 1/4 of circle ?

Comment: yes I want like you mentioned.

Comment: In this case you can't use the CircularProgressIndicator but you have to use drawArc and then animate it.

Comment: Any resources for this how to animate all this stuffs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you want an infinite transition animating the arc of circle.
You can draw the arc using **`drawArc`** and then [**`rotate`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/overview#drawscope) it using:

```
rotate(value) {
  // content is rotated by angle in degrees
}
```

Something like:

```
val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val currentRotation by transition.animateValue(
    0F,
    targetValue = 360F,
    Float.VectorConverter,
    infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = tween(
            durationMillis = 5000,
            easing = LinearEasing
        )
    )
)


Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp)
        .drawBehind {

            //background fixed circle
            drawCircle(
                color = LightGray,
                radius = size.width / 2 - strokeWidth.toPx() / 2,
                style = Stroke(strokeWidth.toPx())
            )

            val diameterOffset = strokeWidth.toPx() / 2
            val arcDimen = size.width - 2 * diameterOffset

            //arc with indeterminate animation
            rotate(currentRotation) {
                drawArc(
                    color = Red,
                    startAngle = 45F,
                    sweepAngle = 90F,
                    useCenter = false,
                    topLeft = Offset(diameterOffset, diameterOffset),
                    size = Size(arcDimen, arcDimen),
                    style = Stroke(strokeWidth.toPx())
                )
            }
        }

)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. It works. I have some doubt `topLeft = Offset(diameterOffset, diameterOffset),` what does it do? why we set `offset`?

Comment: @VivekModi In this way you remove half the stroke width from the total diameter for both sides to have a rect with edges that line up with the midpoint of the stroke of the background circle.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75112301/8266651)