# How to use float resource in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have float value 360F. I created a filed called `float.xml` inside `res/values`.

**float.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="loading_circle_target" format="float" type="dimen">360</item>
</resources>
```

and use like this

```
@Composable
fun LoadingCircle() {
    val currentRotation by transition.animateValue(
        0F,
        targetValue = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.loading_circle_target).value,
        // .. more code in here
    )
    // more code in here
}
```

I am getting error in here

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070346 type #0x4 is not valid                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getDimension(Resources.java:766)                                                                                                           
at androidx.compose.ui.res.PrimitiveResources_androidKt.dimensionResource(PrimitiveResources.android.kt:79)
```

**UPDATE**

I have minimum sdk is 21

Comment: any reason why you are storing 360 as a float?

Comment: @kingston see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75097833/8266651) in here. I am using same code in my sample.. Thanks

Comment: Any new solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you're targetting at least API 29 you can use:

```
val floatValue = LocalContext.current.resources.getFloat(R.dimen.loading_circle_target)

@Composable
fun LoadingCircle() {
    val currentRotation by transition.animateValue(
        0F,
        targetValue = floatValue,
        // .. more code in here
    )
    // more code in here
}
```

Comment: I have minimum 21 api version..

Answer (score 0):

I had to resume to the age old `is_phone` bool since `booleanResource()` supports older API levels. So have

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_phone">false</bool>
</resources>
```

in the **values-sw600dp** folder and set it to `true` in the normal values folder. Then it can be used like

```
@Composable
fun LoadingCircle() {
    val currentRotation by transition.animateValue(
        0F,
        targetValue = if (booleanResource(id = R.bool.is_phone)) 360f else 180f
    )
    // more code in here
}
```